# Solve $dy/dx = (x+y+1)/(3x+3y-1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the following ODE:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x+y+1}{3x+3y-1}$$?
It's not separable, linear or exact. The substitution $z=x+y$ was proposed but when I use that the y term is present both independently and in $\ln(y)$ and I cannot solve for it. Could you please give me some guidelines?

Comment: I don't think you can really solve it, other than with lambert w function. Just leave it in implicit form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with $z=x+y$ we get $$z'=1+y'$$ and our equation is
$$z'-1=\frac{z+1}{3z-1}$$ can you finish?

Comment: I used this method when first solving the ODE, but got as far as
(3/4)y-ln(x+y)=(1/4)x+constant
and I'm not sure how to solve for y since it's both independent and in ln form

Answer (score 0):

For solving a differential equation of this form, consider the lines $x+y+1=0$ and $3x+3y-1=0$ corresponding to the numerator and denominator in:
$$\frac{\mbox{d}y}{\mbox{d}x} = \frac{x+y+1}{3x+3y-1}= \frac{x+y+1}{3\left( x+y\right)-1}$$
In your case, these lines are *parallel* and you substitute $u=x+y \implies u'=1+y'$ to get a separable differential equation in $u(x)$:
$$\frac{\mbox{d}u}{\mbox{d}x}-1 = \frac{u+1}{3u-1}$$

---

For completeness: if the lines were *non-parallel* and their point of intersection has coordinates $(x_0,y_0)$, then the substitution:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
x = t + x_0 \\
y = u +y_0
\end{array}\right.$$
will turn the differential equation into a homogeneous one.